# Azure Logic App: Filter Query Difference between dates should not exceed 10 months

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

Like in SQL Server, we find the difference between dates using DATEDIFF as below, I'm try with OData filter Query in **SQL Server - Get Rows** Connector but I don't see a DateDiff function available.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(month, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) AS DateDiffInMonths from employees where DateDiffInMonths > 10;
```

I've tried below ODATA query by referring few links of Power Automate but it doesn't work as DateDiff doesn't exist in Expressions looks like

```
DateDiff(utcNow(), DateOfBirth, Months ) ge 10
```

Could you please share suggestions on how we can achieve this using OData Filter query or any other way to filter out table records straight away during Get Rows itself?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you create stored procedure, could have comparison value as parameter?  Other option is to calculate a datetime and do a comparison DateOfBirth ge that datetime.  Logic Apps can calculate the time for you in a variable.  Tagging functions and power-automate don't seem to apply.

Comment: The second part of my comment above won't work, I had to do this today :) Found this https://blog.thenetw.org/2020/05/12/azure-logic-apps-sql-connector-strikes-again/

Answer (score 1):

To query for 10 months you can use filter query to be

```
month(hire_date) lt month(@{subtractFromTime(utcNow(),10,'Month')})
```

**For example:-**
Consider I have these records

[image]

[image]

Here is the output

[image]

---

In General you can use

```
year(hire_date) gt year(<Timestamp>) and 
month(hire_date) gt month(<Timestamp>) and 
day(hire_date) gt day(<Timestamp>) and so on
```

You can even change the datetime format and have the comparison for the same.

To query in general

[image]

Here is the output I received

[image]

**REFERENCES:**
[Azure Logic App SQL ODATA Filter on Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143562/azure-logic-app-sql-odata-filter-on-date)

Comment: Swetha, The filter query above is different from the ask.. The difference between the hire date and Today's date should be greater than 10 months. but the sample query in the answer checks for greater than a specific date by year, month and day. Looks like we cannot directly the month difference check using odata existing functions.

Comment: @BVS Can you please check the updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Looks above updated answer too doesn't satisfy the ask, My expected output should contain the employees "Adam-Smith", Samantha, Jim, Larry and Robert as these employees fall in 2015 and 2017, 2020 when compared with the Today's date 25th Feb, 2022 the employees were hired 10 months ago. The updated answer just looks for the month which isn't correct where as I'm looking at difference between today and hiredate is greater than 10months upon which the employees are eligible for bonus for instance. Can the ticks method help?

Comment: As in the question it was mentioned "Filter Query Difference between dates should not *exceed* 10 months" the answer given gives the records of the members who joined in 10 months. In order to get the records whose hiredate is more than 10 months just replace lt with gt.

Comment: Here are the screenshots of logic app and its output
https://i.imgur.com/ZmrVtxN.png and https://i.imgur.com/PcLz5n2.png

Comment: using ticks for odata queries just makes the query complicated but if you do want to know about ticks() you can check the answer in here for better understanding. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71192030/compare-two-dates-in-logic-apps/71192188#71192188

Comment: Apologies if my question is unclear. As per my understanding the solution you proposed with month(hireDate) will just give me the month from the hireDate eg., if the month of hire is JULY (20-07-2020), then this checks of JAN to JULY irrespective of the hireDate is less than utcNow() date by 10 months.

I'm at the solution something like this 
formatDateTime(LastAuditedDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') le formatDateTime(subtractFromTime(utcNow(), 18, 'Month'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')

for reference in SQL this can be achieved with SELECT DATEDIFF(month, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()).

Comment: I think the only alternative is to write a "Azure function" which can replace the "GetRows with ODate filter". With Azure function I'll be able to filter the rows based on Date difference more conveniently.